# Is Gestures missing in General Settings?

Tags: ipad, ipados

Searching `Gestures` in `Settings` indicates there is a `Gestures` under `General` as shown:

[image]

However, there is nothing like a `Gestures` in `General` section. It it missing?

Comment: What is the version of iPadOS that's running on your iPad?

Comment: iPadOS 15.0.2 iPad mini (6th generation)